# multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_lock' while compiling with address sanitizer

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, address-sanitizer, gcc12

I am trying to compile with address sanitizer.

```
gcc12 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=leak -static-libasan my_copy.c -o asan -lpthread
```

Getting this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/ld: my_copy.o: in function `pthread_mutex_lock':
my_copy.c:(.text+0x22): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_lock'; /usr/local/lib/gcc12/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.4/12.0.0/../../../libasan.a(asan_interceptors.o):(.text+0x3a70): first defined here
/usr/local/bin/ld: my_copy.o: in function `pthread_mutex_unlock':
my_copy.c:(.text+0x31): multiple definition of `pthread_mutex_unlock'; /usr/local/lib/gcc12/gcc/x86_64-portbld-freebsd11.4/12.0.0/../../../libasan.a(asan_interceptors.o):(.text+0x3ab0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when I remove `-static-libasan`, it compiles fine.
I want to link `libasan` as static.

*my_copy.c* is just a snippent used to recreate this issue. And this is part of legacy library.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>


int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *mutex, const pthread_mutexattr_t *attr) {
    (void)mutex;
    (void)attr;
    return 0;
}

int pthread_mutex_destroy(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    (void)mutex;
    return 0;
}

int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    (void)mutex;
    return 0;
}

int pthread_mutex_unlock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex) {
    (void)mutex;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I understand why the error is coming, but don't know how get around it.

Answer (score 1):

> my_copy.c is just a snippent used to recreate this issue. And this is part of legacy library.

This legacy library is trying to replace `pthread_mutex*` functions with code which does *nothing*. If your program doesn't use threads, it shouldn't *need* these functions.

But the fact that you are linking with `-lpthread` suggests that your program (or one of the libraries it uses) *does* use threads, in which case the legacy library makes your program *completely* unsafe.

Your best bet is to remove whatever object is defining `pthread_mutex*` functions from the legacy library -- what it's doing is a *very wrong* thing to do!

If you don't want to do that, no reasonable code will work (address sanitizer included), and you may as well just give up.

Comment: @mployed Russian, I get you explanation. But this only happes when I used this option `-static-libasan`, once I remove that, it works. Just that, I need to provied the libasan library path while execution